# How can I use JavaScript to parse Ruby JSON string

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to get the JSON object from a JSON outputted string from a Rails app. Currently in JavaScript I'm doing:

```
data = "<%= @chromosomes.html_safe %>";
```

However, since there are quotes at the beginning and end of the JSON object, it is not being rendered as a JSON object. Instead it is doing something like

```
 data = "[{"name":"YHet","organism_id":"4ea9b90e859723d3f7000037"}]"
```

Is there a way that I can remove the beginning and end quotes so that the object is treated as an array instead of a string?

Comment: I don't know what "html_safe" means exactly, but just as a note, it's not necessarily correct to use HTML-safe escapes ("&lt;" for "<" etc) when you're dropping something directly into JavaScript source.

Comment: @Pointy in this case it probably is correct to use `html_safe`, since he probably wants `[{"name":"&lt;script src='badwebsite.com/bad.js'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;","organism_id":"..."}]` instead of `[{"name":"<script src='badwebsite.com/bad.js'></script>","organism_id":"..."}]`.

Comment: @alpha123 yes sometimes it's correct to use HTML escapes, but not always; for example, if the "organism_id" can contain HTML characters, it may be wrong to replace them if that string is purely intended to work inside JavaScript code and never be injected into the HTML.

Comment: @Pointy correct, although it looks like `organism_id` is a hash or GUID or something else not going to contain < or > or &, and `name` probably will be injected into HTML at some point. I'd say escape.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you do:

```
data = <%= @chromosomes.html_safe %>;
```

Sidenote:

I hope you do something like:

```
@chromosomes = [{ name: "YHet", organism_id: "foo" }].to_json
```

Comment: I could, but JavaScript will not recognize the <%= :(. Thanks though.

Comment: This is clearly the best thing to do; if it's already JSON it should just be dropped directly into the JavaScript source without additional quotes. @PhillipWhisenhunt it's not JavaScript that recognizes the `<%= %>` here; it's your server-side framework. If it works *inside* the double-quotes now, it'll work without them.

Comment: @PhillipWhisenhunt um, that's the point. ERb goes in and processes everything starting with `<%` and ending with `%>` _before the file gets sent to the client_.

Comment: Correct. This is the best way to do it, removing the quotes fixed the issue. Whoops lol, @alpha123 had a major brain fart! Coding to early in the morning!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery you can do the following

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('[{"name":"YHet","organism_id":"4ea9b90e859723d3f7000037"}]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON` object that is included in most of browsers or if you are using jQuery use `$.jsonParse` method that try to use `JSON` object if defined otherwise parse using `eval` or some safer way.

Answer (score 0):

On controller

```
@my_var = MyObj.find_by_id(4).to_json
```

On page in haml way.

```
var my_json = $.parseJSON("#{j @my_var}"); //used JQuery to parser JSON string
```

Answer (score -1):

Use eval:

var dataObject = eval('(' + dataString + ')');